# robot_upstart: Nothing starts on startup

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, robot-upstart, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully executed the command

```
rosrun robot_upstart install myPackage/test.launch
```

and also

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start myPackage
```

But after I reboot or restart, I can confirm by using  `rosnode list` and `rostopic list` that the nodes listed in the launch file never start.
Starting the launch file using `roslaunch` works fine so that's not the issue.
Here's the content of `test.launch`

```
<launch>
      <node name='node' pkg='myPackgage' type='simple_node' />
      <node name='graph' pkg='rqt_graph' type='rqt_graph' />
</launch>
```

**Update 1**: Additional information:

- Starting the service manually doesn't work (even before reboot).

  sudo service myPackage start

No error, but nodes don't run.

- Files installed during the `robot_upstart` install process are still there after reboot.
- There is no log file for `robot_upstart` in `/var/log/`
- There's only one user account, and logging into it I can see the packages and environment variables.

**Update 2**:
I tried launching a couple other nodes and they worked fine. But that one node which receives sensor data still doesn't run. (rqt_graph doesn't run either, but it doesn't matter since it's useless as a daemon.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279291/robot_upstart:-nothing-starts-on-startup/) by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-10**:
I asked [a new, more specific question](https://answers.ros.org/question/279399/ros_upstart-nodes-using-third-party-libraries-are-ignored-python/) about the nodes that don't launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not an answer yet, but I share some things to look at installation issue with `robot_upstart` (not limited to these):

- Does the `service` have an access to the following? Log on as the <s>user</s> account (i.e. usually `root` for upstart) that runs the service process and see:

  - the ROS packages you defined in the launch file you passed to the install script?
  - ROS-related environment variables e.g. `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?
- For a list of resources the install script shows at the end of its run, do you still see them at each location after reboot?
- Do you see your application's log under `/var/log/upstart/`? If so do you see any errors.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-09**:
Thanks. I updated the question.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-01-10**:
I updated slightly; You need to log in as a `root` to see env vars etc., unless you specifically configure your upstart to use another account.